# Docker init failed - WSL still holding onto handles

Tags: docker, wsl2

I tried to restart computer for Docker because I made a .wslconfig file but it throws me this error:

> An unexpected error was encountered while preparing a WSL distro
> destination directory.
>
> The most likely cause for this is WSL still holding onto handles for
> the contents of the directory in question. So shut it down (wsl
> --shutdown), or reboot your machine. If the issue persists please collect diagnostics and submit an issue
> (https://docs.docker.com/desktop/troubleshoot/overview/#diagnose-from-the-terminal).

Error details:

```
2 errors occurred:
    * provisioning docker WSL distros: deploying "docker-desktop-data": preparing directory for WSL distro dir="C:\\Users\\Vlado\\DockerDesktopWSL" distro="docker-desktop-data": removing distro destination dir "C:\\Users\\Vlado\\DockerDesktopWSL": remove C:\Users\Vlado\DockerDesktopWSL\main\ext4.vhdx: The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.
    * checking if isocache exists: CreateFile \\wsl$\docker-desktop-data\isocache\: The network name cannot be found.
```

Does anybody know what it means?

Comment: Care to quote the error message? I can’t tell what is your question and what is a quote contained within your question

Comment: If you already restarted your machine then WSL couldn’t possibly still be holding onto a handle.

Comment: Do you mean that you can't reboot? Or do you get this error after reboot? Does `wsl --shutdown` resolve the problem?

Comment: So *docker system prune -a* will probably solve the symptom causing this error but it will also delete your Docker image. Before running that command post your .wslconfig for us.

Comment: same problem, no solution

Answer (score 2):

I recently got this issue too

Try the following:

1. Stop Docker Desktop
2. Run the following command in your terminal `wsl --unregister docker-desktop`
3. Run Docker Desktop again (Will recreate the distro)

Works so far on my end, I will continue to monitor.